# Compare attributes from multiple elements of same class to see if they are the same?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, comparison

Say I have the following set of elements, how can I compare to see if all the "data-type" attributes are the same?

I know I could iterate through them all using .each() and store the "last" one and compare them one by one, but it seems there should be an easier and more elegant way.  Something like the following (totally fictitious) function...

```
<span class="item" data-type="server"></span>
<span class="item" data-type="server"></span>
<span class="item" data-type="server"></span>

$('.item').attr('data-type').sameFunc() = true
```

or

```
<span class="item" data-type="printer"></span>
<span class="item" data-type="server"></span>
<span class="item" data-type="server"></span>

$('.item').attr('data-type').sameFunc() = false
```

Comment: What are you trying to set to true/false? A variable or an attribute on the HTML?

Comment: A variable.  I'm doing some logic for a context menu.  The user can select multiple items.  I need to know if all the items selected are of the same type or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check if all the elements with the same class has the same data attribute:

```
$('.item').length == $('.item[data-type="server"]').length;
```

just see if the number of elements with that class matches the number of elements with that class **and** the data attribute.

**EDIT:**

another way without knowing the value of the data attribute:

```
var same = $('.item').length == $('.item').filter(function(i) {
    return $(this).data('type') == $('.item').eq(i-1).data('type');
}).length;
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ut5ht/)

Comment: Oh that's a brilliant way of doing it.

Comment: I guess I could get the first type and compare the lengths using that, yeah>?

Comment: Without knowing what data-value to check for, you'd just be checking blindly if something matches. If they all have only one data attribute, I guess you could compare the data objects. A filter and just checking if the current data-value matches the data-value of the previous element etc should work ?

Answer (score 0):

```
function same(attr){
    return $('.item').length == $('.item[data-type="'+attr+'"]').length;
}

var isSame = same($('.item:first-child').attr('data-type'));
```

Will take the first's attribute and then pass it in, comparing it to the others...